# Error in using extra intents in FragmentTab

Tags: android, android-intent, logcat

This is the error **logcat**:

```
01-09 21:44:27.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25935): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 21:44:27.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25935): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xx.xx.xx/xx.xx.xx.Mainclass}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-09 21:44:27.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25935):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
01-09 21:44:27.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25935):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
01-09 21:44:27.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25935):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
01-09 21:44:27.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25935):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
01-09 21:44:27.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25935):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 21:44:27.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25935):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-09 21:44:27.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25935):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
01-09 21:44:27.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25935):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 21:44:27.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25935):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-09 21:44:27.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25935):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
01-09 21:44:27.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25935):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
01-09 21:44:27.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25935):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-09 21:44:27.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25935): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-09 21:44:27.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25935):    at xx.xx.xx.FragmentTab1.onCreateView(FragmentTab1.java:52)
01-09 21:44:27.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25935):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
01-09 21:44:27.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25935):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
01-09 21:44:27.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25935):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
01-09 21:44:27.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25935):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
01-09 21:44:27.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25935):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
01-09 21:44:27.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25935):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:551)
01-09 21:44:27.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25935):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1164)
01-09 21:44:27.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25935):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5114)
01-09 21:44:27.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25935):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
01-09 21:44:27.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25935):    ... 11 more
```

I used to use the code fine, but I switched to use tabs in my app which caused the problem.

this is the `code` around the problem:

```
Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras(); 

TextView Title = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);

if (extras != null) {
    userName = extras.getString("title");
    Title.setText(userName);
}
```

`Title.setText(userName);` is **line 52**.

Comment: Search for the `TextView`(which I'm assuming is part of the fragment) using the view you inflate in the `onCreateView()` method and not by using `getActivity()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first as Title is a variable it should be written lowercase.
The problem will be that the TextView is null because `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tvTitle)` returns null everytime.

Instead you have to save the views you need during the Fragments `onCreateView()` method, like here:

```
private TextView textView;

...

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, container, false);
    textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewId);

    return v;
}
```

Comment: the textview is from the xml

Comment: Where do you inflate the xml? Do you override onCreateView() in the fragment?

Comment: your second answer is right, I should've used v. not getactivity. thank you.